# How to get values using pd.shift

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]

I am trying to populate values in the column `motooutstandingbalance` by subtracting the previous row `actualmotordeductionfortheweek` from previous row `motooutstandingbalance`. I am using pandas shift command but currently not getting the desired output which should be a consistent reduction in `motooutstandingbalance` week by week.

Final result should look like this
[image]

Here is my code

```
x['motooutstandingbalance']=np.where(x.salesrepid == x.shift(1).salesrepid, x.shift(1).motooutstandingbalance - x.shift(1).actualmotordeductionfortheweek, x.motooutstandingbalance)
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please show a sample dataframe of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: added sample dataframe of what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
start_value = 468300.0
df['motooutstandingbalance'] = (-df['actualmotordeductionfortheweek'][::-1]).append(pd.Series([start_value], index=[-1]))[::-1].cumsum().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Basically what I'm doing is I'm—

1. Taking the `actualmotordeductionfortheweek` column, negating it (all the values become negative), and reversing it
2. Adding the start value (which is **positive**, as opposed to all the other values which are negative) at index `-1` (which is before `0`, not at the very end as is usual in Python)
3. Reversing it back, so that the new `-1` entry goes to the very beginning
4. Using `cumsum()` to add all the of values of the column. This actually work to subtract all the values from the start value, because the first value is positive and the rest of the values are **negative** (because `x + (-y) = x - y`)

Comment: this does not work for me, the column instead gets populated with Nan values